# Entity Framework core Include() is not working after upgrading from version 3.1.2 to 5.0.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a project that was running with .net core 3.1. After upgrading to .net 5 and entity framework core to 5.0.3, the include is not working anymore.

I have these classes

```cs
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AnswersId")]
    public Answer Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Answers { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

The relation is defined as follows:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
        .HasOne(q => q.Answers);
}
```

and this simple LINQ:

```cs
return _context.Questions
        .Include(q => q.Answers)
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

however. the include is not working after the version upgrade. By not working i mean the returned values doesn't include Answers. Main entity only is returned and all the fields in the child are null.

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? Build error, runtime exception, unexpected behavior, etc? Please be specific.

Comment: what is it that's not working? just no values being returned?

here's a list of the EF core 5.0 breaking changes  => 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#required-dependent

One thing you should do to check what's changes is to run the profiler and observe what SQL Ef is creating for you

Comment: The returned value is the main entity only without the child entity.

Comment: I checked all the breaking changes before posting the question.

Comment: double check the data, looks correct.

Comment: saying that not seeing Foreign keys, please double check how you set up relations

Comment: The data is correct in the database, It's working fine with .net core 3.1.

Comment: include the table structure... insure  AnswersId...is mapped.

Comment: AnswersId is mapped as FK

Comment: @ThunderBolt what do you mean by **Main entity only is returned and all the fields in the child are null** . Are getting an `Answers` object inside your `Question` (a.k.a, the Include IS working) but the properties of the included answer are all null ?

Comment: @dglozano yes, I get the Answers field but the object is null.

Comment: @ThunderBolt are you %100 sure you didn't change anything else apart from the update of the library? For example, I have the suspicion that your OnModelCreating is wrong, but then it would have been wrong also in the previous version.

Comment: @dglozano I only changed the version in csproj file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not a 100% sure if this is the issue, since you said that it was working fine previously, but it might be that your relationship is not configured properly in `OnModelCreating` since it is lacking a call to either `WithOne` or `WithMany` to be correct.

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasone?view=efcore-5.0#overloads):

> After calling this method, you should chain a call to WithMany(String) or WithOne(String) to fully configure the relationship. Calling just this method without the chained call will not produce a valid relationship.

There is a [breaking change in EF 5 related to the semantics of a required nagivation property from the principal (Question) to the dependant (Answer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#required-on-the-navigation-from-principal-to-dependent-has-different-semantics) which *might* be the explanation for the wrong behavior after upgrading the library.

So let's give a shot to this... try to configure your relationship like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
        .HasOne(q => q.Answers);
        .WithOne()
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Comment: Adding .WithOne() fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had a wrong using while still compiling and no runtime error - nothing to do with an upgrade.

Wrong:
`using System.Data.Entity;`

Fixed with:
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: This answer saved my sanity. 
What amazes me is that this issue compiles, runs and even works for *some* more basic Linq statements. 
Also I was going from version 2.2.6 to 3.1.32 at the time. So this is not limited to 5.0.x.

I believe it was Visual Studio auto adding the wrong using statement.